# Excel: Force a default value if user-entered value is less than a minimum

Tags: excel, validation

I have a cell (F24) where users may enter a percentage. However, if the user enters a percentage less than a specified value (C24/G22), I want the cell value to automatically default to that value.

Data Validation gets me almost there, but instead of automatically inserting the minimum value it simply pops up with an alert. I'd prefer (and it makes the most sense for this particular application) that the process be automatic.

Is there something simple that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see how to do this without some VBA:
If you put the following in the sheet where this occurs, it should meet your needs.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells = Cells(24, 6) And Cells(22, 7) <> 0 And Cells(22, 7) <> "" Then
        If Target.Value < Cells(24, 3) / Cells(22, 7) Then
            Target.Value = Cells(24, 3) / Cells(22, 7)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

What this does:

- 1st it checks to see if the target(focus) is at F24 AND that the G22 cell is not 0 or blank  If all those conditions are not met, do nothing.
- 2nd it checks to see if the F24 entered value is less than C24/G22, if it is it replaces the value entered with the C24/G22 result. if the value is equal to or greater than C24/G22, then it does nothing.

Still thinking about a non-VBA way but so far nothing's coming to mind.

Comment: This seems to work, but because my VBA skills are not very strong I only have a vague sense of why it works. But this is a good jumping-off point to start tinkering. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @dherman updated answer to explain VBA; but nothing new on doing it w/o vba.

Comment: @dherman you won't get a solution without VBA *within* the same cell. Without VBA, you can do the trick by using another cell

Comment: @Boud thanks for the clarification. I may just suck it up and use another cell. Not as elegant, but it could do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind to have the 'correct' data in another cell :

User will type in cell F24, add column G so G24 will contain :

=IF(G24<(C24/G22),"default",G24)